# Getting the email Id of the User register in Appstore in swift

Tags: ios, app-store, swift2

I don't know it is the valid question or not. How can we get the login id of the user from which it has been login to the Appstore in iPhone. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Apple could not allow you to use the `private` information access within the application.

For more information please look into the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/information/iOS_Program_Information_4_3_15.pdf) and read the 3.3.1 section.